# How to use the DataRow to get the columns name?

Tags: c#

The function return `DataRow`, and I want to get the columns header name?  How to get it? I am programming in C#.

This is the code:

```
DataRow[] teDR=null;
DataRow[] DR = BizManyRecQuery.LoadForm.ManyRecQuery("f225839e-313a-488f-be47-55340ea46e34","prjProcessId",teDR);
if(DR!=null)
{
    //get the columns header name
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following should  work

```
foreach (DataColumn c in DR[0].Table.Columns) 
{
    MessageBox.Show(c.ColumnName);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Have modified it now. thanks to King King & Grant

Answer (score 2):

The columns header name can be achieved only from `DataTable.Columns`, so you can try this:

```
if(DR!=null&&DR.Any()) {
   var headerNames = DR[0].Table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                          .Select(col=>col.ColumnName).ToList();
   //remove ToList() if you want.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The DataRow class has a reference to the Table that it belongs to:

```
DR[0].Table.Columns[# or name]
```